# Javascript find and scroll to text

Tags: php, javascript, scroll

I need a bit of Javascript that will find some text in the html page and then scroll to that point.

So something like "Are you a Lib Dem or Tory supporter and how do you feel about the deal?" would scroll down to the bottom of the page for this bbc news page: http://news.bbc.co.uk/1/hi/uk_politics/election_2010/8676607.stm

Im hoping there is a built in function for both the find text and scroll.

Comment: Do you control the page that you want to scroll?

Comment: Yes this is to be used on my own application

Comment: Sounds like a challenge for jQuery and its selector engine. Have you tried something like $(window).scrollTop($("*:contains('Are you a Lib Dem or Tory'):first").scrollTop()); ?

Comment: Ive tried that in an onload function and didnt work, something im doing wrong?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Try this. It works on the site you provided:

```
$(window).scrollTop($("*:contains('Are you a Lib Dem or Tory'):last").offset().top);
```

It finds last, deepest element that contains given phrase on the page and scrolls to it.

---

If you want to do the same thing without jQuery you need to use XPath becasue CSS didn't get `contains()` selector.

```
window.scrollBy(0, document.evaluate("//*[text()[contains(., 'Lib Dem')]][last()]", document.body).iterateNext().getBoundingClientRect().top);
```

If you need to scroll to the first occurrece, not the last one, delete `[last()]` from this code.

Comment: Good man! That worked very well, would it be possible to add some animation to that so it scrolled down really fast? I have Jquery and ui installed. Thanks so much!

Comment: In regards of animating scrolling take a look at this: http://www.learningjquery.com/2007/09/animated-scrolling-with-jquery-12

Comment: hey can you make that code on js?

Comment: @AshutoshAnand Sure. I updated my answer with the code that does the same but doesn't require jQuery.

Answer (score 4):

You can also use what google is using to scroll to and highlight specific portions of a search result when you visit the page.

It generates a URL like this:

[https://www.inc.com/peter-roesler/heres-what-googles-new-highlight-feature-means-for-your-website.html#:~:text=If%20you%20see%20a%20featured,saw%20in%20the%20featured%20snippet.](https://www.inc.com/peter-roesler/heres-what-googles-new-highlight-feature-means-for-your-website.html#:%7E:text=If%20you%20see%20a%20featured,saw%20in%20the%20featured%20snippet.)

It is kind of nifty. The syntax seems to be:

```
https://example.com/#:~:beginning_of_text,end_of_text
```

See the following blog post for a few more details:

https://web.dev/text-fragments/

It is supported by version 80 and beyond chromium based browsers. So, limited support right now, but depending on your use case, it could be useful.

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar issue in trying to scroll to any occurrence except the last one.  (e.g. "n" occurrence).  [The below code uses jquery, which you have to [download](https://jquery.com/download/) and include.]

The following code will cycle through each occurrence of the selected input text, starting with the first one.  I left in some alerts I was using to see what was happening with each call.

```
    var i = 0;

function findtext(text){
var x = $("*:contains('" + text + "'):eq(" + i + ")").offset();
var y = $("*:contains('" + text + "'):last").offset();
i++;
if (x.top == y.top)
{alert("no more occurences of this term");}
else if (x.top > 0)
    {
    alert("Top: " + x.top + " Left: " + x.left + " i:" + i);
    $(window).scrollTop(x.top);
    }
else
    { //call itself again
        alert("i:"+i);
        findtext();            
    }
```

}

I also had to put in "if not 0" logic, because if I use "*" for the element type.  There were several parent elements picked up which started on line zero, so I wanted to skip them.  If you know for instance that your word will be within a  tag, you could change it to the following to cut down on the extra calls.

```
var x = $("div:contains('" + text + "'):eq(" + i + ")").offset();
```