# Scroll to text link

Tags: javascript, jquery, text, scroll, find

I would like to make a link that finds some text and scrolls to that point. I can't add span or div tags.

I have found this and ideally I would like to turn it into a link and add animation. Thanks

```
$(window).scrollTop($("*:contains('Are you a Lib Dem or Tory'):last").offset().top);
```

[Original stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2820086/javascript-find-and-scroll-to-text)

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that this is the sort of thing a standard `<a>` tag does already without JavaScript, if you can add an `<a name="jumppoint">` tag around or at the start of that text and then another `<a href="#jumppoint">` tag where you want your visible link. You could insert such an `<a>` dynamically with jQuery.

But if you're determined to use that code you can add a link as follows:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="$(window).scrollTop($('*:contains(\'Are you a Lib Dem or Tory\'):last').offset().top);">Your link text here</a>
```

Of course that's kind of ugly so you'd probably be better off creating a function:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="findLink(); return false;">Your link text here</a>

function findLink() {
    $(window).scrollTop($("*:contains('Are you a Lib Dem or Tory'):last").offset().top);
}
```

If you want some animation add it in the findLink() function.

Comment: Thanks for your help nnnnnn, I think the find text is beyond my grasp. Is it possible to dynamically insert an anchor link where the text is "Project context" I can only insert plain text into this CMS.