# Scroll to Text without ID on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, frontend, scrolltop, scrollto

I have multiple rows with text artikels that have a title above it aswell. I'm looking for a search function that scrolls to the correct titles have been put in the search bar after a button click. Now this text doesn't have a class or ID atm and it's also loaded it from a database with `<b>Titel: " . $row['titel'] . "</b>` In this case it would be "I am a test title" for example.

I've tried this (and multiple other) functions on the button click:

```
$(window).scrollTop($("*:contains('I am a test title'):last").offset().top);
```

[Found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2820086/javascript-find-and-scroll-to-text)

But since my text is loaded in from a database it doesn't regocnize it (i assume). When i try this exact same function with an `<p>I am a test title</p>` at the bottom of the page it **does** scroll to text inside it.

This function has been succesfull aswell, but instead of the red border i would like a scroll to for exmaple.

```
$('*:contains("I am a test title")').each(function(){
 if($(this).children().length < 1) 
      $(this).css("border","solid 2px red") });
```

[Found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58834583/scroll-to-text-without-id-on-button-click)

I have been stuck with this problem for a while and wasn't able to find any solutions. Any help in the right direction is much appreciated.

My full code i use to load in multiple articles:

```
 if ($res = mysqli_query($link, $sql)) {
  if (mysqli_num_rows($res) > 0) {
      if ($_SESSION['login_user'] == true) {

          echo "<table class='tableArtikel'>";
          while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)) {

              $artikelRow = $row['artikel'];
              $rowArtikelId = $row['Artikel_id'];
              $rowTitel = $row['titel'];
              $rowTag = $row['tag'];
              echo "<form method='POST'>
          <input type='hidden' name='id' value='" . $rowArtikelId . "'>
          <div  class='container'>
          <th style='font-size: 1vw; font-family: sans-serif;     border-bottom: 1px solid #8f8f8f; padding-bottom: 23px;     padding-top: 23px;' class='" . $row['tag'] . "'><div><b style='font-size:20px;'>Titel: " . $row['titel'] . "</b></div><br> <i>Tags: " . $row['tag'] . " </i><br> Geupload door: " . $row["username"] . " <br> Laatst bewerkt: " . $row['edit_date'] . " door: " . $row['lastedit'] . "  <br><br>
                 <textarea name='content' id='summernote' class='summernote' style='margin-bottom: 5px;' >" . $artikelRow . "</textarea>
                <input type=\"submit\" name=\"submit\" value=\"Submit\" class='defaultButton'>
                </form>
                <button data-id='" . $rowArtikelId . "' id=\"myBtn$rowArtikelId\" class='openModal defaultButton'>Edit</button>
                <form method='POST'>
                   <input type='hidden' name='id' value='" . $rowArtikelId . "'>
                   <input type='submit' value='Delete' name='deleteArt' data-id='" . $rowArtikelId . "' id=\"myBtn$rowArtikelId\" class='deleteArt defaultButton'>
                </form>

               <!-- overlay   -->     
                <div id=\"myModal$rowArtikelId\" class=\"modal\">
                  <div class=\"modal-content\">                     
                    <span data-id='" . $rowArtikelId . "' class=\"close\">&times;</span>
                    <form method='POST'>
                    <br><input type='hidden' name='id' value='$rowArtikelId' >
                    <p>Titel</p>
                    <input value='$rowTitel' name='updateTitel' class=\"defaultInput\" style='color:black'><br>
                    <br><p>Tag</p>
                    <input value='$rowTag' id='updateTag' name='updateTag' class=\"defaultInput\" style='color:black'>
                    <input type='submit' name='submitPopUp' id='submitPopUp' class=\"defaultButton\" value='submit'>
                    </form>
                  </div>                 
             </div>    
             <!-- overlay -->      

          </th> 

          <tr>
             <th>

            </th>
          </tr>

          </div>";

          }
          echo "</table>";
          echo "</div>";

      }
  }
```

}

Comment: If the code you've included works in some situations and not others, you should include one of the failing situations in your question. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example Chances are, the issue is due to something you haven't shown us, making it very difficult for us to help.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not possible to scroll to  a text ( you should put Ids ), but if you still wants to do it without Id you could search your term with :

```
var elem =   $('*:contains("I am a simple string")');

$([document.documentElement, document.body]).animate({
        scrollTop: elem.offset().top
    }, 2000);
```

Comment: Since the first function i mentioned does actually work, but not with text from the database i figured there must be a way to do it.

Comment: What do you mean by " text from the database ", text is loaded after the page ? because this actually works with things loaded from Db. If you type my code in your console right now, you will scroll to the top ! and `var elem =   $('*:contains("I am a simple string")');

$([document.documentElement, document.body]).animate({
        scrollTop: elem.offset().top
    }, 2000);` to the bottom

Answer (score 0):

> I think the issue is that your js runs before your document gets
>   ready.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        // do something
    });
});
```

You can place your code in the document ready function and it only executes when the DOM has loaded, in contrast, to directly using the scroll event.

You can learn more at: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/What-is-document-ready-method-in-jQuery